# inserting in table emp1234 but got an error in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

This is what I tried:

```
emp1234(user_id,age,city,country,height,mobile_no,name,sex,state,weight) FROM '/tmp/user.csv' WITH HEADER = FALSE;
```

But it returns the following error:

> error -
>   Failed to import 17 rows: WriteTimeout - Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'},  will retry later, attempt 1 of 5

Comment: code and error indentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable reason for it is that you have different DC name in the replication factor settings of keyspace, than in your cluster.

Get DC name(s) via `nodetool` status, check the names in the settings of the keyspace (via `DESCRIBE keyspace_name;`), they should be the same, including character case. If they are different, change replication factor via

```
alter KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC_name': X};
```